# Is it Possible To use Selenium Without Installing the Chrome App?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

As the title says, is it possible to use Selenium without downloading the whole Google Chrome application? I was wondering about this, because you can run Selenium on replit without any issues, but when I tried running it on VS Code on my computer (which doesn't have Google Chrome Installed) I keep getting errors, despite the fact that I have the latest chromedriver version installed.

I was using selenium to log into a website where I can access upcoming assignments, and wanted to  make a simple webapp where the program opens up the login page, I enter the credentials (which uses a Google sign in), and Selenium interacts with the website to collect the required data. I was also trying to use Selenium to store the required cookies so that I don't need to manually log in every time. The program itself does not run in VS Code since I don't have Chrome installed, and I wanted to ask how a webapp running on a server could use Selenium, because chrome is required. I'm still new to automation, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: All that Selenium does is control a real browser.  You need Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or some other major browser in order to use Selenium.  Replit has a copy of Chrome installed.

Comment: Is there any way to add a copy of chrome into my own project files? Would it need to be chrome binary, or is there some other way?

Comment: Why can't you just install Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, Selenium is a controller for a browser instance, not an actual browser itself and so requires the chromedriver and Chromium to be installed. From the
[Chromedriver getting-started page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

> Ensure Chromium/Google Chrome is installed in a recognized location

> ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for your platform. You can also force ChromeDriver to use a custom location by setting a special capability.

As long as you have the chrome binary in a location that ChromeDriver can identify, Selenium should work.

That being said, [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/) supports multiple browsers so if you really don't want to install Chromium, maybe trying to interface with Edge, Safari, or Firefox would be applicable to your situation.